# cupcake to FroYo marketplace problems (app not shown to some people - or listed on appbrain)

Tags: android, google-play, android-2.2-froyo

After reading another question, explaing to allow apps2sd I should change my android target to 2.2, keep minsdk at 4 and add installpref to manifest - this works great. However I noticed after uploading this update that my sales dropped, and free downloads. My brother in japan can no longer see my app!
 My question is - how can I keep my app on the international market, and use froyos SDK?

working link:
http://www.androidblip.com/android-games/wheelz-2d-physics-platformer-90018.html

broken on appbrain:
http://www.appbrain.com/app/wheel-2d-physics-platformer/com.chozabu.android.BikeGame

Extra information!
I uploaded copy of my game - where the only change is to return SDK to 1.6
http://www.appbrain.com/app/wheelz-international-trials/com.chozabu.android.BikeGameBeta
it shows up on appbrainz!
Thanks

Comment: I am just reverting back to sdk 1.6 for now...

Answer (score 0):

> change my android target to 2.2, keep minsdk at 4 and add installpref to manifest

Well there's your issue right there. `Cupcake` is 3 `Donut` is 4. If it still doesn't work leave me a comment below.

Check out the version codes [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#CUPCAKE)